# Declaring CONST in a C# class and using it in different Pages

Tags: c#, static, constants, uwp, readonly

I was trying to clean my code, and I came across a very simple scenario, where I want all my URL's and JSON strings which are all time const to declared in one single file, but I couldn't figure it out. In android I normally use to make a simple CONST.Java file, but here a simple CONST.cs doesn't seem to work.

What is the approach in UWP for having const variable used all across the project

Comment: Define *doesn't seem to work*, what error do you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: You can store such values in App.Config or some class with all variables with `const` keyword.

Comment: It appears as though something's broken or, at least, not as you expected. If you need a more specific suggestion, you'll have to make the question more specific.

Comment: It was broken, StringUtils.cs is a example of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a file to hold all your constant files says StringUtils.cs
you can then declare all your constants in the file like this

```
public const string Apikey = "qwerty";
public const string CustomerId = "123456";
```

You can then reference your constants using `StringUtils.Apikey` to get the api key

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the constant value in a static property in a globally accessible class in your project